# Redshift SQL conditional dense rank

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How would I "pause" a customer's rank if the difference in hours vs their previous booking is less than 24? i.e. a conditional `dense_rank()`

```sql
with tmp_table as (
select 532 as customer_id, '2020-01-09 18:14:47'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 532 as customer_id, '2020-01-09 18:22:13'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 532 as customer_id, '2020-01-09 18:26:07'::timestamp as log_date union all
--
select 981 as customer_id, '2020-01-09 16:53:52'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 981 as customer_id, '2020-01-09 17:08:28'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 981 as customer_id, '2020-01-11 17:25:24'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 981 as customer_id, '2020-01-14 17:32:10'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 981 as customer_id, '2020-01-14 21:49:12'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 981 as customer_id, '2020-01-17 19:15:22'::timestamp as log_date union all
--
select 1983 as customer_id, '2019-11-05 10:30:58'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 1983 as customer_id, '2019-12-02 13:58:52'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 1983 as customer_id, '2019-12-05 17:25:01'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 1983 as customer_id, '2019-12-11 13:58:24'::timestamp as log_date union all
select 1983 as customer_id, '2019-12-12 14:15:25'::timestamp as log_date
)
select *
, datediff(hour, lag(log_date, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by log_date), log_date) as hour_diff
, rank() over (partition by customer_id order by log_date) as rnk
from tmp_table
order by customer_id, log_date
;
```

output is this:

```
customer_id|log_date           |hour_diff|rnk|
-----------|-------------------|---------|---|
        532|2020-01-09 18:14:47|         |  1|
        532|2020-01-09 18:22:13|        0|  2|
        532|2020-01-09 18:26:07|        0|  3|
        981|2020-01-09 16:53:52|         |  1|
        981|2020-01-09 17:08:28|        1|  2|
        981|2020-01-11 17:25:24|       48|  3|
        981|2020-01-14 17:32:10|       72|  4|
        981|2020-01-14 21:49:12|        4|  5|
        981|2020-01-17 19:15:22|       70|  6|
       1983|2019-11-05 10:30:58|         |  1|
       1983|2019-12-02 13:58:52|      651|  2|
       1983|2019-12-05 17:25:01|       76|  3|
       1983|2019-12-11 13:58:24|      140|  4|
       1983|2019-12-12 14:15:25|       25|  5|
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
customer_id|log_date           |hour_diff|rnk|
-----------|-------------------|---------|---|
        532|2020-01-09 18:14:47|         |  1|
        532|2020-01-09 18:22:13|        0|  1|
        532|2020-01-09 18:26:07|        0|  1|
        981|2020-01-09 16:53:52|         |  1|
        981|2020-01-09 17:08:28|        1|  1|
        981|2020-01-11 17:25:24|       48|  2|
        981|2020-01-14 17:32:10|       72|  3|
        981|2020-01-14 21:49:12|        4|  3|
        981|2020-01-17 19:15:22|       70|  4|
       1983|2019-11-05 10:30:58|         |  1|
       1983|2019-12-02 13:58:52|      651|  2|
       1983|2019-12-05 17:25:01|       76|  3|
       1983|2019-12-11 13:58:24|      140|  4|
       1983|2019-12-12 14:15:25|       25|  5|
```

i.e. if `hour_diff > 24` then `rank() over (partition by customer_id order by log_date)` else "pause rank"

what I tried to do is set a case statement where if the `hour_diff` < 24 then take the `lag()` of the log_date else take the log_date and then do a `dense_rank()` on this new log_date

the problem I encountered with that is that if a customer does multiple bookings within 24 hours then it won't really "pause" the rank number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to determine where the value should increment.  Then use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum( case when prev_log_date > log_date - interval '24 hour' then 0 else 1 end ) over (partition by customer_id order by log_date) as rnk
from (select t.*,
             lag(log_date) over (partition by customer_id order by log_date) as prev_log_date
      from tmp_table t
     ) t;
```